# Loading a testing set into a Dvector generator that works for the training set

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch

So I am having this issue where I created Dvectors and they are working for the testing set, from a checkpoint.

```
model.load_state_dict(checkpoint['state_dict'])
model.eval()
with torch.no_grad():
    dvectors = model.generateDVec(x)
```

the generateDVec():

```
def generateDVec(self, x):
    batch_size, num_chunks, features  = x.shape
    x = x.reshape((batch_size * num_chunks, 1, features))
    embeddings = self.encoder(x)  # TODO
    embeddings = embeddings.reshape(batch_size, num_chunks, -1)
    return self.classifier.generateVector(embeddings) #dvectors
```

However I am getting this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> model.load_state_dict(checkpoint['state_dict'])   File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py",
> line 1051, in load_state_dict
> raise RuntimeError('Error(s) in loading state_dict for {}:\n\t{}'.format( RuntimeError: Error(s) in loading state_dict for
> Model:    size mismatch for classifier.proj.weight: copying a param with
> shape torch.Size([462, 1024]) from checkpoint, the shape in current
> model is torch.Size([168, 1024]).     size mismatch for
> classifier.proj.bias: copying a param with shape torch.Size([462])
> from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([168]).

The 462 is there because in my training file path there were 462 people, and in testing - 168... What could go wrong there?

Comment: What do you refer to as "people"? Are you referring to some kind of dictionary? Or embedding?

Comment: Sorry. I mean speakers. I have a dataset for training consisting of 462 speakers with chunks of their sentences.